# Spark Yarn-client mode across network via VPN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have been trying to get Spark yarn-client mode working through VPN. More specifically, spark driver will be launched locally from my laptop, while the yarn cluster is in its own private network reachable through a non-bridged VPN.
The first challenge was to make the spark driver service reachable from yarn-cluster since the VPN is one-way, my laptop is not routable from the cluster.
I managed to get this working by adding an entry in /etc/hosts to point a public domain name to my local network IP, something like

> 192.168.0.6 spark.driver.mydomain

Then I set spark.driver.host=spark.driver.mydomain.
Now spark driver can successfully bind to spark.driver.mydomain, and tell yarn application manager to connect to spark.driver.mydomain. I also need to configure spark.driver.mydomain to point to my public IP by modifying my domain's DNS, and configure firewall to make the service publicly available. 
Now I can run spark from my laptop to drive the cluster, almost there. However the SparkUI doesn't work. There is no way to connect to SparkUI despite of the message says it's suffcessfully started at spark.driver.mydomain:4040. I opened all the ports through my local network's firewall using DMZ. I also tried to use local network IP address. I can notice it is being redirected to yarn resource managers link, http://resourcemanager/proxy/application_id but just get timed out eventually, and I haven't figured out how the proxy thing works.
The spark session also occasionally spits out warning messages like

> WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@executor:port] has failed, address is
>   now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].

The basic spark actions all works despite of the warning message.
There are still quite a few concerns and questions

- Does the communication between spark driver and yarn cluster contain unencrypted data in this scenario? Is there any data security concerns ( assuming the VPN is secure).
- SparkUI is not accessible, which is intolerable.
- Warning messages
- Is it really a good practice to run driver from a remote network in yarn-client mode? There are certainly other benefits to do so, but is the framework designed to do this?

Finally, here is a JIRA issue that may lead to more general solutions. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5113